# How to join two tables in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, join

I try to join 2 tables and output the result:

In model:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('news');
$this->db->join('authors', 'authors.id = news.author_id');
```

In view files:

```
foreach($item as $row):
    echo $row->id;
endforeach;
```

When I run the code above, it will output `id` column from `authors` table.
My question is how do I echo `id` column from `news` table?

Both `news` and `author` tables have column named `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `echo $row->author_id`

It seems like the field you want in the news table is `author_id` instead of `id`.

**EDIT** Otherwise you can use the `as` sql keyword in your select statement to give a different name to your field.

```
$this->db->select('*, news.id as my_news_id');
```

And then do, `echo $row->my_news_id`

Comment: i want to echo id from news table